# How to do "select current_timestamp" in hsqldb?

Tags: sql, database, hsqldb, embedded-database

Oracle:

```
select systimestamp from dual
```

MySQL:

```
select current_timestamp
```

SQL Server:

```
select current_timestamp
```

PostgreSQL:

```
select current_timestamp
```

The question is, how can I get the current timestamp in [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/)? I use version 1.8.0.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write

```
select current_timestamp from tablename
```

where `tablename` is a real table in your database.

The result of the query is only the current timestamp.

Comment: Thanks, but with hibernate I do session.createSQLQuery("select current_timestamp from users") and I get empty list for .list() and null for .uniqueResult(). The table exists. If I put a non existent table I correctly get java.sql.SQLException: Table not found in statement [select current_timestamp from qwerty]

Comment: is the table you are using empty? for some reason I did a couple of tests and seems that if the result of the select is an empty list, you don't have the timestamp, if the result of the select is a list of rows, you get as many timestamps as the number of rows..

Comment: I know this is an old question, but if you want to write generic code (e.g. in a reusable library), that does not depend on specific a specific database, you could try using something like:

`SELECT TOP 1 current_timestamp FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_TABLES`

Comment: If the Table could be empty you need to wrap the timestamp with max aggregation and coalesce:

`select coalesce(max(current_timestamp()), current_timestamp()) from tablename`

Answer (score 28):

In a select I use

```
 SELECT CURRENT_DATE AS today, CURRENT_TIME AS now FROM (VALUES(0))
```

Comment: I prefer this solution as it doesn't require me to have any tables (for a plain connection test).

Comment: I found this answer more useful. My goal was to just do a simple select statement to verify the syntax. Most SQL implementation allow that without a FROM clause. This was a great work around.

Answer (score 11):

[@alexdown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909702/how-to-do-select-current-timestamp-in-hsqldb/909729#909729) is quite right -- under 1.8 you need a one-row relation to do this, like Oracle's `DUAL` or the InterBase/Firebird `RDB$DATABASE` table.

When you move to the 2.0 series, however, you'll be able to use the SQL-99 "VALUES constructor" without reliance on a one-row relation:

```
sql> VALUES (current_timestamp);
2010-04-22 15:22:40.997
```

If you need to rename the column from the vendor-specific defaults that VALUES picks, you can always employ a select: `SELECT * FROM (VALUES (current_timestamp)) v(my_new_name)`

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
CALL current_timestamp
```

to retrieve the current timestamp. According to a discussion on the HSQL mailing list this is much more efficient than doing a dummy select from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_TABLES`.

Answer (score 4):

With HSQLDB 2.1 and later you have all the options.

With the connection property hsqldb.syntax_ora, hsqldb.syntax_pgs, hsqldb.syntax_mss or hsqldb.syntax_mys=true you can use the forms supported by other databases. The equivalent SQL is `SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE`, and similar for other dialects.

The native, SQLStandard form, supported by HSQLDB in all modes is this:

```
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: It's actually `SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE`. You were missing the "SQL" @fredt.