# How to return default value when no rows return from table

Tags: sql, null, hsqldb, default-value

When the table ERRORMESSAGE contains no rows that satisfy the "WHERE" condition, IFNULL fails and I get null, not the default value provided in the IFNULL clause.

```
select IFNULL(errorCode , 'NOERRORCODE') as "errorCode", 
    IFNULL(errorText , 'NOERROR') as "errorText" from 
    (select errorcode, 
        IFNULL((select errorText from STATIC_ERRORCODES a 
        where a.errorcode = b.errorcode), '') as errorText 
     from ERRORMESSAGE b  where b.route_id = 'IPN4' 
     order by b.row_index)
```

When there are no rows in ERRORMESSAGE with route_id = 'IPN4', the output should be:

```
errorCode = NOERRORCODE
errorText = NOERROR
```

But I get null/empty values. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `NOT EXISTS` and `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT errorCode, errorText
FROM ERRORMESSAGE WHERE <condition>
UNION ALL
SELECT 'NOERRORCODE', 'NOERROR'
FROM ERRORMESSAGE
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ERRORMESSAGE WHERE <condition>)
```

You need to replace `<condition>` with actual criteria. So, when there is are row exists, then `SELECT` after `UNION ALL` will get executed, which will show static row.

Please note: I have never used HSQLDB, so I wasn't sure how to show static rows, but I used as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909702/how-to-do-select-current-timestamp-in-hsqldb)