# SELECT UUID() in HSQLDB

Tags: mysql, database, hsqldb, uuid

Does anyone know how to retrieve UUID via HSQLDB.

For example when i try

```
SELECT UUID();
```

via MYSQL it works fine. But the same statement doesn't work with HSQLDB. 
The following methods achieve the corresponding purpose

```
VALUES (UUID())

CALL(UUID())

SELECT UUID() FROM (VALUES(0)) t;
```

Is there a way which is same for mysql and hsqldb?
HSQL doc says that UUID has been activated. http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html

Thanks.

Comment: is there any hack where statement like SELECT UUID() FROM (VALUES(0)) would also be possible to work with mysql?

Comment: HSQLDB requires the `FROM [table]` part... i found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909702/how-to-do-select-current-timestamp-in-hsqldb but is't with current_timestamp() but i think the same method can be used for UUID()

Comment: `SELECT UUID() FROM (SELECT 0) t` might work in both MySQL (know for sure it works in MySQL) and HSQLDB

Comment: tried it now, it does't work when i specify table name. SELECT UUID() FROM (SELECT 0) t works only with mysql

Comment: "Is there a way which is same for mysql and hsqldb? " see mine answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on the MySQL compatibility mode in HSQLDB and it will allow your SELECT statement:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/compatibility-chapt.html#coc_compatibility_mysql

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way which is same for mysql and hsqldb?

Only way i can think off. 
Create a table DUAL in HSQLDB

```
CREATE TABLE DUAL (
  id INT
);
```

So you can use

```
SELECT UUID() FROM DUAL LIMIT 1;
```

Then the query should work the same in both MySQL and HSQLDB. 
DUAL in MySQL is a non existing dummy table.